# Spring MVC NumberFormatException

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I have to entities which are in @OneToMany realtion.
I have an error when I'm trying to get unitPrice from my entity. Could anybody help me to resolve this problem?

My entities:

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="Product")
    public class Product {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int idProduct;
        private String status;
        private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
        private List <Repository> repository;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="Repository")
    public class Repository {

        @Id
        private int idRepository;
        private int quantity;
        private double unitPrice;

        @ManyToOne
        private Product product;
```

view:

```
<c:forEach items="${products.repository}" var="product">
                            <p>${product.unitPrice}</p>
                            </c:forEach>
```

ERROR:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "repository"
```

Comment: were you trying to display the list of products?can  u post the controller code where your are setting the products object

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the code below to display the `unitPrice` in `repository`.
In the code below, `products` represents a `List` of `Product` objects where each `Product` object has a `List` of `Repository` objects.

```
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
    <c:forEach items="${product.repository}" var="repo">
        <p>${repo.unitPrice}</p>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```